# Cannot allocate memory for array, rdkit converting to numpy array error

Tags: python, numpy, rdkit

I have a list of 2215 molecules encoded as 2048 bit vectors. What I'm trying to do is to create 2D array from it. I am using `rdkit` [library](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.html) to convert to numpy arrays. The code worked without a problem few weeks ago and now there is a memory error but I can't figure out why. Can anyone provide a solution?

I tried to make the list smaller and reduced it down to two vectors. I thought it would help but the error stills pops out after some time of processing. That leads me to believe that I in fact do have enough memory.

```
# red_fp is the list of bit vectors

def rdkit_numpy_convert(red_fp):
    output = []
    for f in fp:
        arr = np.zeros((1,))
        DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(f, arr)
        output.append(arr)
    return np.asarray(output)

# this one line causes the problem
x = rdkit_numpy_convert(red_fp)
```

this is the error:

```
MemoryError  Traceback (most recent call last)
MemoryError: cannot allocate memory for array

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-91594513666c> in <module>
----> 1 x = rdkit_numpy_convert(red_fp)

<ipython-input-13-78d1c9fdd07e> in rdkit_numpy_convert(red_fp)
      4     for f in fp:
      5         arr = np.zeros((1,))
----> 6         DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray(f, arr)
      7         output.append(arr)
      8     return np.asarray(output)

SystemError: <Boost.Python.function object at 0x55a2a5743520> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: Can you share an example definition of the `red_fp` that you are using? Also, mentioning that you are using rdkit and tagging the question as such would attract the right people to help you with the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by example definition. One fingerprint is just 2048 integers (either 0 or 1, mostly 0).
fp is then a list of 2215 fingerprints, red_fp is just a small number of fingerprints to check if it'd worked with smaller amount of information

Comment: The function is not using `red_fp` but `fp`. Where does `fp` come from? is it in the global scope? is this your intention? Perhaps you want the function to use red_fp?: `for f in red_fp:`

Comment: It was first written with fp. I didn't notice it, now it is fixed (for f in red_fp) but the error persists.

Comment: For me your code works with 5979 molecules, RDKit 2019.03.3, numpy 1.16.4, Python 3.7.3, Windows 7 and 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that the fingerprints you are using are not compatible with this method for converting to numpy arrays.

I am not sure what type of fingerprint you are using, but assuming you are using morgan fingerprints, I did some quick experiments and this method seems to hang when I use the 'GetMorganFingerprint' method versus the 'GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect' method. I am not sure why this problem occurs but I assumed it was due to the fact that the first method produces a UIntSparseIntVect versus an ExplicitBitVect although I found that when I attempted the same method with a fingeprint produced by the 'GetHashedMorganFingerprint', which also returns a UIntSparseIntVect it works fine.

I suggest if you are using morgan fingerprints to try the 'GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect' method

Edit:

I did a couple more experiments

```
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1')

fp = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(mol, 2)
print(fp.GetLength())
'4294967295'

fp1 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, 2)
print(fp1.GetNumBits())
'2048'

fp2 = AllChem.GetHashedMorganFingerprint(mol, 2)
print(fp2.GetLength())
'2048'
```

As you can see the fingerprint from the first method is huge, my initial thought is that this fingerprint is in an unfolded state, hence a sparse data-structure is used, this would explain why you have problems trying to allocate memory for a fingerprint of this dimension.

Comment: @Jozef Hi, if this is the solution to the problem could you please mark it as the accepted answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've heard of `rdkit`, but it looks like this is a `Boost` wrapper for `C++` code.

From the docs, https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.html

the second argument to `ConvertToNumpyArray` is `destArray`.

```
rdkit.DataStructs.cDataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray((ExplicitBitVect)bv, 
    (AtomPairsParameters)destArray) → None :¶
```

My guess is that this function tries to put the converted values into the `destArray`.  It isn't trying to allocate new memory itself (as a conventional `numpy` constructor would), but rather just fill the array that it was given.

If that guess is right, then the error is in the

```
arr = np.zeros((1,))
```

That `arr` only has space for one float, 8 bytes.  `arr` needs to be big enough (and the right `dtype`) to hold the result produced by `Convert`.

Is there any documentation or examples illustrating the use of this conversion?  When asking questions about low traffic tags like `[rdkit]` it helps if you include some links to documentation and example code.

---

I glanced at other `[rdkit]` SO.

[How can I compute a Count Morgan fingerprint as numpy.array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809506/how-can-i-compute-a-count-morgan-fingerprint-as-numpy-array)

suggests that I'm wrong.  The accepted answer uses

```
np.zeros((0,), dtype=np.int8)
```

which allocates 0 bytes to its data buffer.

And another that uses `np.zeros((1,))`

[ValueError when doing validation with random forests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864729/valueerror-when-doing-validation-with-random-forests)